# How to plot a bar graph with scrollable x axis in JupyterLab?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-lab

I am trying to plot bar graph using `%matplotlib inline`. Data catergory on x axis is in large number, so I want to make x axis scrollable.

Hosting JupyterLab using jupyter/datascience-notebook image. I am not able to use matplotlib widget or notebook backend to make the graph interactive

```
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
.
.                                 //some logic
.
.
wordsForPlottingBarGraph = wordsDF.head(15)
plt.bar(wordsForPlottingBarGraph.get('words'),wordsForPlottingBarGraph.get('frequency'))
```

Output :
 [image]

This becomes more clumsy on x axis when I try to increase data category on x axis

Comment: Is the problem that you cannot get `notebook` or `widgets` backend to work? In that case a lot more information about your environment is needed.

Comment: It was not working because I was using datascience-notebook docker image

Comment: @BenT I tried using bokeh. Is it possible to get it working using matplotlib widget or notebook?

Comment: It will be harder with bokeh (not sure why @BenT wants to trick people into using bokeh in comments of matplotlib questions??). If you have notebook or widgets backend working, you can use a `Slider` for scolling.